# How to find a good financial planner in India

Tags: india, financial-advisor

For last few months I am looking for a god financial adviser but cound not found one here in India. I read [This](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-does-one-find-a-good-financial-advisor) SO question but this is not about India. Is there any directory or associations of financial planners in India. A financial adviser is different from a chartered accountant. Right?

Answer (score 1):

A financial adviser is very different from chartered accountant.

In India the concept of financial advisory is still evolving in recent times. Till couple of years back most of the advisory was from agents or distributors of insurance or mutual fund products tyring to sell their product.
With the recent changes like limiting/removing commissions on most of the financial products and encouraging agents to undergo financial certifications, the future looks good.

Currently most of the leading brokrage houses [Religare, Reliance, Sharekhan, to name a few] along with leading Banks and Insurance houses have rebranded the agents as "Financial Advisors", the chartered accountants have also started offering Financial Advice. However most still lack the skill of advising as per the goals of individual. Rather than taking a hosistic view, the advice is mostly to buy insurance and invset in stocks/funds.

The best way in current situation is to read various magazines and articles and try out a few agents from your Bank or good Brokers and see what value add they bring.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But the problem here is that if agents usually try to sell their products rather than evaluating your goals. I read economic times, especially the articles on personal finance. I think that educating myself on personal finance is the best I can do at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately as of now like you said agents try to sell stuff. It may take sometime [2-4 years] for the market to evolve. Also most of the individuals do not want to pay the advisor a decent sum, as they believe he would make money out of investments... so it would take some time for mind shift of customer to pay someone purely for advice and not buy anything directly from him.

Answer (score 0):

The financial planning standards board of India has a list of [certified financial planners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Financial_Planner) from across India. You can filter it out by categories of state, city, type of employment.

http://www.fpsbindia.org/scripts/CFPCertificantProfiles.aspx

Try choosing an independent person who charges a fixed fee for their consultation. This kind of person won't have any bias toward funds and will keep your financial goals and welfare in mind. Also look at their profiles and what they have written, because that will be a first indicator of their quality of work.